# How to reshape a 3-D array to 2-D in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working with a timeseries data pipeline.
I created a list of sequences as
sequences=list()
Then I appended array items of the shape (30,201) on each iteration where 30 is the row count and 201 is my features length. Total items are around 2000. At the end I comnverted my list to array with

```
3Darray=np.stack(sequences) # I also tried np.array(sequences) as well
```

Now, my array has the shape(2000,30,201).
I want to restore my original 2D features data with the shape (2000*30,201). But when I try

```
3Darray.resahpe(3Darray.shape[0]*3Darray.shape[1],201) 
3Darray.shape
```

No change in shape happens. What I'm doing wrong here?

**I tried to follow [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35338832/7344164) answer but I did succeed.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the result of `3Darray.resahpe(3Darray.shape[0]*3Darray.shape[1],201)` to a new variable, see the documentation of [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):
*This will be a new view object if possible; otherwise, it will be a copy. Note there is no guarantee of the memory layout (C- or Fortran- contiguous) of the returned array*